# call 2 or more views with one controller in spring java

Tags: java, spring, jsp

i want to call 2 views within one controller in spring with java.
for example

```
this.controller.view('header');
this.controller.view('body');
this.controller.view('footer');
```

how can i do that?
or it is possible in spring?
or can you suggest any other way to do it?

and can i call a view inside a view.
for example in `view/login.jsp`,

```
<table><tr><td>
<jsp>this.controller.view('login_form')</jsp>
</td></tr></table>
```

yeah, all the codes i wrote there are not valid jsp language, but that is the concept i want to do in this project.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Reuse of templates and code?
There may already be a good pattern available to you, but first 
It may be better to start by clarifying your objective

Comment: i want to call 2 different views within one controller. my objectives is i want to reuse the same thing that i have in all of the pages, for example, the header menu.

Comment: i found examples that defines all the menu and the body of the page in the same view file. but that is not what i want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you would like to reuse fragments of a JSP (header, footer) across multiple JSP pages. If that is the case, consider using one dedicated view (for example login_form.jsp) and using JSP [include](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/11/syntaxref1112.html) statements to incorporate the 'common' fragments from that JSP page.

As an example (of login_form.jsp):

```
<jsp:include page="header.jsp"/>
<!-- login_form specific page content goes here -->

<jsp:include page="footer.jsp"/>
```

This would allow you to reuse common  header and footer content across multiple JSP pages.

I would also recommend having a look at Spring MVC ([documentation](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html)), it is a pretty good approach for Spring based web apps.